# php content I'm calling using ajax is only visible for a fraction of seconds

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a PHP file for validation form; now I'm learning to use ajax to avoid a page refresh.

So, I want to call a PHP file using ajax and show it in my HTML.

And it's happening, but the problem is the data from PHP that is shown in my HTML is visible just for a fraction of seconds, and I need it to stay.

Just in case I'm using a local server to test this.

PD: I don't want to use Jquery.

```
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  var phpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  phpRequest.open('POST', 'form.php');
  phpRequest.onload = function(){
    phpMessage.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', phpRequest.responseText);
  }
  phpRequest.send();
})
```

Comment: Prevent the default action of `<form>` submission `function(event){event.preventDefault(); // do stuff}` which refreshes `document`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I have my form like this <form method="post" onsubmit="blockSubmit();"> and then in my js I have the function 'function blockSubmit(event){event.preventDefault()}' but it doesn't work.

Comment: Because `event` is not defined within `submit` event handler. Try using `.addEventListener()` instead of event attribute to call event handler function.

Comment: Oh I forgot that, thank you for your time buddy!